# How do I combine data from 2 columns into 1 column in mysql and have it saved?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, concatenation

I am in the process of creating a new table of mock user id's and looking to combine first and last names into the new column UserIDs. I am successful in using the CONCAT string to combine the values; however, I have been unsuccessful in combining that with an `INSERT INTO` statement.

This is what I am attempting:

```
INSERT INTO person_userid
CONCAT(FirstName, LastName) as UserID 
from person_UserID.
```

Comment: Remember that commands like `INSERT` are [exhaustively documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) if you ever want to know how to use them. There is no mystery as to how they operate.

Comment: Probably you want a space:  `CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use an insert select  you should use this way

```
 INSERT INTO person_userid (user_id)
 select CONCAT(FirstName, LastName) 
 from person_UserID
```

but if the rows already exists  could be you need a simple update  ..

```
 update person_userid 
 set user_id = CONCAT(FirstName, LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the INSERT statement is incorrect. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) is the INSERT reference.

```
INSERT INTO person_UserID (person_userid) VALUES (CONCAT(FirstName, LastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE person_UserID SET UserID = CONCAT(FirstName, LastName)
```